# ¿Cómo obtengo los 10 mayores valores de una lista de tuplas? Python 3.8

Tags: python, lista

lo que pasa es que tengo que crear un código que de una lista de tuplas de la forma (ID_pelicula,promedio) tal que me permita extraer los 10 ID's y sus respectivos promedios, el código completo que tengo es muy largo porque tengo otros requerimientos previos, pero la parte en el que intento extraer las películas es esta:

```py
for pelicula, promedio in lis:
    if pelicula not in top_10:
        if float(promedio)>=M:
             M=promedio
             mayor=pelicula
        top_10[mayor]=M
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que debes tratar de simplificar tu código para hacer un código mínimo que represente el problema, de lo contrario corres el riesgo de recibir respuestas inconclusas que no representan la solución a tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que tu tienes una **lista de tuplas**, se me ocurrió este código:

Primero, tenemos una lista de tuplas (id, promedio) de películas:

```
peliculas = [
  (1, 5),
  (2, 5.5),
  (3, 6),
  (4, 6.5),
  (5, 9),
  (6, 9.5),
  (7, 10),
  (8, 4),
  (9, 8.5),
  (10, 8),
  (11, 7.5),
  (12, 7),
]
```

Ahora, vamos a ordenar las películas de mayor a menor mediante su promedio:

```
pels_sorted = sorted(peliculas, reverse=True, key=lambda tupla: tupla[1])
```

Y por último, vamos a obtener las primeras 10 películas para hacer el top 10:

```
top_10 = pels_sorted[:10]
```

Espero te sirva, es un código simple y funcional. Si tienes alguna duda con las funciones que usé, puedes ponerlo en los comentarios y yo con gusto las respondo.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo, pero hay muchas mejores alternativas. Aun así creo que esta es la que mejor se entiende al explicarlo, si estás comenzando a programar.

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
top_diez = []

for x in range(10):  # Número de veces que ejecutamos este bucle
    maximo = max(lista)  # Buscamos el máximo valor
    top_diez.append(maximo)  # Lo añadimos a una nueva lista
    top = lista.remove(maximo)  # Lo eliminamos de la lista antigua, para que el próximo "máximo valor" no incluya este valor

top_diez.sort()  # Ordenamos la lista
print(lista)
print(top_diez)
```

> lista: [1,2,3,4,5]
>   top_diez: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

Funciona, pero el problema es que hemos destrozado la lista original. 
Ahora que entiendes el problema más común, podemos optar por una alternativa en la que **NO** eliminamos valores de la lista original:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

lista.sort(reverse=True)  # Ordenarla de forma inversa
top_diez = lista[:10]  # Y capturar los 10 primeros elementos
print(lista)
print(top_diez)
```

> lista: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>   top_diez: [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6]

Como ves, en esta alternativa la lista original mantiene todos los elementos.